# Alternative for lead() function in SQL Server 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want the same output as lead function do for window function. I want to do it for SQL Server version 5.0

Table Name: Table

```
EventID  CID  Date
123      1    01-12-2020
123      2    01-12-2020
123      3    01-12-2020
345      2    05-12-2020
345      4    05-12-2020
456      1    07-12-2020
456      4    07-12-2020
567      1    08-12-2020
```

Output

```
ID      CID     Date       ColumnA
123      1    01-12-2020    07-12-2020
456      1    07-12-2020    08-12-2020
567      1    08-12-2020    Null
123      2    01-12-2020    05-12-2020
345      2    05-12-2020    Null
123      3    01-12-2020    Null
345      4    05-12-2020    07-12-2020
456      4    07-12-2020    Null
```

Comment: The only correct answer is to upgrade you SQL Server. You are on an unsupported version.

Comment: @DaleK Select EventID,CID,Date,(Select Max('Date') from table as t group by CID where t.Date<t1.date) from table t1

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL version 5" ?? SQL Server has versions 2005, 2008 , 2008 R2 (all of these **unsupported by now**), 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 - none of those are "SQL v5" - please be clearer in what you're using

Comment: [edit] any improvements into the question.

Comment: Strangely, even when they were using version numbers, not years, there [never was a version 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server)

Comment: @marc_s I meant, am using 5.7.30 version

Comment: @ANSH - that strongly suggests that you're using [tag:mysql], not [tag:sql-server]. First get clear what product you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a correlated subquery in lieu of not having access to the `LEAD()` function:

```
SELECT
    EventID AS ID,
    CID,
    Date,
    (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Date FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.CID = t1.CID AND t2.Date > t1.Date
     ORDER BY t2.Date) AS ColumnA
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    CID,
    Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

**Edit:**

You tagged your question for SQL Server, explaining why you received this and the other answers.  If your RDBMS really be MySQL, then use this version:

```
SELECT
    EventID AS ID,
    CID,
    Date,
    (SELECT t2.Date FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.CID = t1.CID AND t2.Date > t1.Date
     ORDER BY t2.Date LIMIT 1) AS ColumnA
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    CID,
    Date;
```

Comment: When i run this query, it pop up the following error:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 t2.Date FROM testing.table1 t2
      WHERE t2.CID = t1.CID AND t2.Date > t1.Dat' at line 5

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL, but in any case check my slight edit for a version which should work on MySQL.

Comment: its working fine.Surprised :) Can you please explain how where condition is helping to find the next date of an event.

Comment: The subquery is finding the next greatest date in the same `CID` group.  Check the logic closely.

Comment: When we run this, then from one table it map one row with all row of another table and to get one value for it we use Limit 1. Am i right

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen I m trying to achieve with this Select a.EventID,a.CID,a.Date,b.Date from (Select EventID,CID,Date,t2.Date as ColumnA FROM testing.book8 t2 ) as a left join
(Select * from testing.book8 t1) as b on b.CID = a.CID AND b.Date > a.ColumnA order by a.CID
However I get two rows with the same condition, I want to understand how Limit 1 is helping you to achieve the output. And how it give only next value in output without group by clause

Comment: I have answered your original question multiple times.  If you have a new question, then ask it elsewhere.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CID] ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS [RowID]
    FROM [Table] 
)
SELECT DS1.EventID  
      ,DS1.[CID]
      ,DS1.[Date]
      ,DS2.[Date] AS ColumnA
FROM DataSource DS1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[RowID] = DS2.[RowID] - 1
```

Comment: @gotqn Its a window function.

Comment: @ANSHULSHARMA https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3572301/RowNumber-function-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Comment: My current sql version is 5.7 and its not allowing me to run this query.